# How to Unhide stepper when we select particular row in tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uistepper

I have created a stepper in a CustomCell of a `UITableView`. However, I would like the stepper to only be visible when a particular row is selected. To this end, I tried the following:

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.customStepper.hidden=NO;
```

and in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.customStepper.hidden=YES;
```

But the stepper is still hidden. What am I missing?

Comment: if you want to Unhide stepper than you should write **cell.customStepper.hidden = NO** in **tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I clarified some of your question, and hopefully the intent is easier to understand. You say "the stepper is still hidden." It might be a good idea to add some information about what you're doing that you expect should un-hide the stepper. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface BRNCategoryViewController ()
{      
  NSMutableArray *arySelectCategory;
  NSMutableArray *aryCategory;
}

 - (void) viewDidLoad
{
     arySelectCategory=[NSMutableArray new];
}


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     return aryCategory.count;
 }



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BRNCategoryCell *cell=[[BRNCategoryCell alloc]initWithOwner:self];

     if ([arySelectCategory containsObject:[aryCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
      {
           cell.customStepper.hidden = NO;
      }
      else
      {
           cell.customStepper.hidden = YES;
      }

            return cell;

  }



 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
      [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

      if ([arySelectCategory containsObject:[aryCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
      {
           [arySelectCategory removeObject:[aryCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      }
      else
      {
           [arySelectCategory addObject:[aryCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      }
            [tblEventCategory reloadData];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.customStepper.hidden=YES;
```

And

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
VideosCell *cell = (VideosCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.customStepper.hidden = NO;
```